# C# format decimal to string

Tags: c#

I need to format the Decimal variables Latitude=9113267; Longitude=59300357;
to string format 9,113267 and 59,300357

Thx
john

Comment: Ending with "thx" does not make it more polite.

Comment: To be clear, what should the comma be? A "decimal" point (by US standards) or a place separator (I'm confused because it's not every 3rd grouping, and the original numbers don't have that format).

Comment: [MSDN is your friend...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VascoP is right in how to convert the number to a "proper" decimal but he is wrong about how to convert those decimal values to a string. the ToString method has an overload whose signature is

```
public string ToString(IFormatProvider provider)
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ebe5aks.aspx

You can use this to create a culture specific string. The examples on the linked page show how to do it but for completeness of answer an example might be:

```
(Latitude/1000000).ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB") // Outputs with a "." decimal separator
(Latitude/1000000).ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE") // Outputs with a "," decimal separator
```

I assume you have a specific culture that you want to be able to understand this so you should use the correct culture. That makes it much easier to change later if you want (eg you can pick up the culture from a global config setting) or have a user preference for the number format, etc.

Also if you start using custom formats (eg to put thousand separators in) then the cultureinfo object will again do the right thing.

It should also be noted at the end of all this that you may just need the .ToString if the default culture is actually the one you are using. You didn't provide that info though so I just assumed that a simple ToString wouldn't be doing the trick.

Comment: @VascoP: Cool. Glad you've learnt something new. Update your answer to reference that it is not best practice, etc. and I'll take off my -1. I don't like voting down people relatively new to the site since I know how exciting getting your rep up can be. I just really didn't want anybody thinking that was the best way to do it. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(Latitude/1000000).ToString().Replace('.', ',');

(Longitude/1000000).ToString().Replace('.', ',');
```

EDIT: Although this works, as stated by Chris, it is not best practice. You should use his solution instead.

Comment: -1, sorry, if I ran that I would get decimal points (.) not commas (,)

Comment: @Kieren:  If OP is using the Norwegian culture, he would get commas.  Vasco is likely using the Portuguese culture which will also yield commas.  The English-UK culture will yield a decimal point.  Vasco should add that the decimal separator is dependent upon culture.

Comment: -1 There are perfectly good ways in .NET to get the correct decimal separator using cultures that doing it this way with Replace is definitely a bad practice.